# Regular expression in R to remove pairs

Tags: r, regex

I have a code that outputs a pair of integers as "(1, 21)", as a string. The integers are always between 1 and 99.

I want to extract the integers into an array as numeric. How can I do this? I've done some research and it seems regex is the way to go, but I'm unsure exactly how to do this here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are several base R one-liners.  These each produce a data frame.  Use `as.matrix(...)` on that if you want a matrix/array.  (2) seems particularly compact.

**1) trimws/read.table** trim non-digits off the ends using trimws and then use read.table to read it in giving the data frame shown.

```
x <- c("(1, 21)", "(2, 22)", "(3, 33)")  # input

read.table(text = trimws(x, white = "\\D"), sep = ",")
##   V1 V2
## 1  1 21
## 2  2 22
## 3  3 33
```

**2) gsub/read.table** Another approach is to convert each non-digit to a space and then use read.table:

```
read.table(text = gsub("\\D", " ", x))
##   V1 V2
## 1  1 21
## 2  2 22
## 3  3 33
```

**3) strcapture** Define a regular expression with captures to use with strcapture.

```
strcapture("(\\d+), (\\d+)", x, data.frame(V1 = integer(0), V2 = integer(0)))
##   V1 V2
## 1  1 21
## 2  2 22
## 3  3 33
```

**4) chartr/read.table**  Use `chartr` to replace `(` with a space and then use read.table defining the comment character as `)`.

```
read.table(text = chartr("(", " ", x), sep = ",", comment.char = ")")
##   V1 V2
## 1  1 21
## 2  2 22
## 3  3 33
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gsub` to remove `(` and `)` using `[()]` and then use `strsplit` to split at `,` . `unlist` the retuned list and convert it to `as.integer` and create a `matrix` or `array`.

```
matrix(as.integer(unlist(strsplit(gsub("[()]", "", x), ", ", TRUE))), 2)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    3
#[2,]   21   31
```

Data:

```
x <- c("(1, 21)", "(3, 31)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Tidyverse way

```r
x <- c("(1, 21)", "(33, 99)", "(1, 7)")
library(tidyverse)
map_dfr(str_split(str_replace(x, '\\((\\d+)\\,\\s(\\d+)\\)', '\\1 \\2'), ' '), ~ set_names(.x, c('A', 'B')))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   A     B    
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 1     21   
#> 2 33    99   
#> 3 1     7
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>